# Can I compile a piece of code in FreeBSD based on its versions

Tags: c++, freebsd

I want a way something like this in C++:

```
if (__FreeBSD__8)

        abc();
else if (__FreeBSD__10)

        xyz();
```

Currently I could see only

```
 if ( __FreeBSD_) 

        do_something();
```

Thanks in advance for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Actually, [the proper way](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/porting-versions.html) is to include `<sys/param.h>` and check `__FreeBSD_version` define. It gives you very accurate version value, so you can even check for presence of specific features. The list of FreeBSD versions and features [is here](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/porters-handbook/versions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

We could do something like this:

```
#if (defined(__FreeBSD__) && (__FreeBSD__ == 8))

           abc();
#elif (defined(__FreeBSD__) && (__FreeBSD__ == 10))


           xyz();
```